# Stage is hidden when dialog is shown

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have this code which displays confirmation dialog to exit application.

```
    public class DialogPanels
{

    public void initClosemainAppDialog(final Stage primaryStage)
    {

        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event)
            {
                event.consume(); // Do nothing on close request

                // Dialog Stage init
                final Stage dialog = new Stage();
                dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

                // Frage - Label
                Label label = new Label("Exit from the program");


                // Button "Yes"
                Button okBtn = new Button("Yes");
                okBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                    {
                        //primaryStage.close();  
                        //dialog.close();
                        //Platform.exit();     
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });

                // Button "No"
                Button cancelBtn = new Button("No");
                cancelBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                    {
                        primaryStage.show();
                        dialog.close();
                    }
                });

                // Layout for the Button
                HBox hbox = new HBox();
                hbox.setSpacing(10);
                hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                hbox.getChildren().add(okBtn);
                hbox.getChildren().add(cancelBtn);

                // Layout for the Label and hBox
                VBox vbox = new VBox();
                vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                vbox.setSpacing(10);
                vbox.getChildren().add(label);
                vbox.getChildren().add(hbox);

                // Stage
                Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
                dialog.setScene(scene);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

The problem is that when close the main application the dialog box is displayed and the main stage is hidden. I want to display the dialog box in front of the main stage. Can you help me to correct this?

***UPDATE***

I tested this code, it's working but when the dialog is displayed the mainstage is not responsible(frozen). How I an make the mainstage responsible when I display dialog?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the proper relationships between primaryStage and dialog stage. Here's a hint to get you going:

```
...
dialog.initOwner(primaryStage);
dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
dialog.showAndWait();
```

You can find more information in Oracle's [JavaFX 2 JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html).

## More example code (edit)

I'm using s`etOnHiding(..)` instead of `setOnCloseRequest(..)`:

```
stage.setOnHiding(new AskUserIfHeReallyWantsToQuitWindowHandler(stage));
```

I extracted your code into a seperate event handler class and fixed the issues I mentioned (sorry, I am little short on time right now):

```
public class AskUserIfHeReallyWantsToQuitWindowHandler implements EventHandler<WindowEvent> {
    private final Stage primaryStage;

    public AskUserIfHeReallyWantsToQuitWindowHandler(final Stage primaryStage) {
                    Objects.requireNonNull(primaryStage);
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(final WindowEvent event) {

        event.consume();

        final Stage dialog = new Stage();

        final Button okBtn = new Button("Yes");
        okBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(final ActionEvent event) {
                dialog.close();
                primaryStage.close();
            }
        });

        // Button "No"
        final Button cancelBtn = new Button("No");
        cancelBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(final ActionEvent event) {
                dialog.close();

                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        primaryStage.show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // Layout for the Button
        final HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setSpacing(10);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hbox.getChildren().add(okBtn);
        hbox.getChildren().add(cancelBtn);

        // Layout for the Label and hBox
        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vbox.setSpacing(10);
        vbox.getChildren().add(new Label("Do your really want to exit?"));
        vbox.getChildren().add(hbox);

        // Stage
        final Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
        dialog.setScene(scene);
        dialog.initOwner(primaryStage);
        dialog.initModality(Modality.NONE);

        dialog.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to help you with the primary stage closing. There's a lot in your code to work on (for example use `Platform.exit()`), consuming the event and so on.

What *exactly* is not working properly?

Comment: The dialog is displayed behind the main stage.

Comment: Can you post more code and which platform and JavaFX 2 version you are exactly running? Window handling seems fine on Linux.

Comment: I use the latest JavaFX. This is the complete source code: http://pastebin.com/6KQJ5QfN

Comment: In your code both showAndWait() and show() are called. I'm gonna edit my post with more code which works for me...

Comment: Very strange, you call this event with the code `AskUserIfHeReallyWantsToQuitWindowHandler dialog = new AskUserIfHeReallyWantsToQuitWindowHandler(primaryStage);`? Correct? When I close the mainstage the dialog is not displayed. The program is just closed normally.

Comment: As the name says, it is not a dialog but a `WindowHandler`. Can you paste your code again?

Comment: You forgot to add the `EventHandler` to the primaryStage in the `start(..)` method of your application which is why the dialog is not displayed:

`primaryStage = setOnHiding(new DialogPanels(primaryStage));`

If you still got a problem keep pastin' the code :-).

Comment: Yes, I get the expected result but I noticed a small problem. When I click the dialog's `No` button the backstage is reloaded. Is this normal or it can be avoided?

Comment: Maybe reloading of the screen is caused by `setOnHiding`. Can I replace it with something else?

Comment: This is a a bug in JVM 7 https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-24879 It's working fine on JVM 8.

Comment: Interesting - so I wasn't too far off calling JavaFX a bit bug riddled :-)!

Answer (score 1):

Consume the closing event and set the owner of the stage if you do not want to see another window when the windows are minimized:

```
@Override
public void handle(WindowEvent event)
{
    event.consume(); // Do nothing on close request

    // Dialog Stage init
    final Stage dialog = new Stage();
    dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    dialog.initOwner(primaryStage);

    // other stuff
}
});
```

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem. One more question. When the dialog is displayed the main stage is frozen (not responsible waiting for the dialog) how I can display the dialog and also let the main stage working?

Comment: dialog.initModality(Modality.NONE)

Comment: I changed the `Modality` to NONE but now main stage is closed when I display dialog(back on the start).

Comment: @PeterPenzov. Main stage is not closed in my case. What is the version of JavaFX you are using?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I have tested on 2.2.21-b11, and it is working as expected on my Windows 7 64bit machine.